# How to write compareTo method for point as oneliner

Tags: java

I want to know if it possible to write this method in one line.  I need to compare y-coordinates and break ties using the x-coordinates.

```
 // comparing y-coordinates and breaking ties by x-coordinates
    public int compareTo(Point p) {

        if (y < p.y) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (y > p.y) {
           return 1;
        }
        if (x < p.x) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (x > p.x) {
         return 1;
        }
       return 0;
    }
```

"note. The question is asked out of interest to see if there is any original out of the box solution. It is evident that the presented
               solution is good as"

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Remove all newlines.

Comment: Shorter doesn't mean better. It's preferable to have a readable program than have a short program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (but I wouldn't recommend it for readability):

```
return y < p.y ? -1 : y > p.y ? 1 : x < p.x ? -1 : x > p.x ? 1 : 0;
```

I haven't bothered to check, but I would guess that the compiler generates exactly the same byte codes as for your original code.

Comment: You could also combine `y < p.y` and `x < p.x`, as well as the other two conditions, to make it *even shorter*... if that's what the OP is going for. (For whatever reason.)

Comment: @Eric - I don't think you can. The `x` values are irrelevant unless the `y` values are equal. I'd appreciate being shown wrong, though. :)

Comment: http://ideone.com/lQMMo0 Have a look for yourself! ;) Feel free to modify the test cases, I came up with those in... about 15 seconds.

Comment: @Eric - It took me about 10 seconds to come up with: `compare3(1, 0, 0, 1) == -1` while `compare1(1, 0, 0, 1) == compare2(1, 0, 0, 1) == 1`. Better luck next time. :)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing that out, though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't care about the magnitude of the return value, only its sign, you can do it this way:

```
return y == p.y ? x - p.x : y - p.y;
```

---

edit: As Ted Hopp points out, this approach only works as long as the subtraction doesn't overflow. If you know that `x` and `y` are always positive, or that the difference between them is always less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, then you can use this version.

Here's another alternative that should work on all inputs:

```
return y == p.y ? ((Integer) x).compareTo(p.x) : ((Integer) y).compareTo(p.y);
```

If you're using Java 1.7, you can use the simpler

```
return y == p.y ? Integer.compare(x, p.x) : Integer.compare(y, p.y);
```

Comment: Not a good idea. This doesn't work when there is overflow.

Comment: @TedHopp, your example of `y == (Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 1)` and `p.y == -y` actually works with the original code as shown. Comparing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` doesn't, though, for example.